# Custom format (or regex) with moment.js

Tags: momentjs, handsontable, pikaday

It is possible to define some custom format containing a string to be ignored by moment.js ?

I have a date string like the following:

`14-Apr [not valid]`

I do not have the possibility of changing the date before passing it through moment.js and I'm wondering if moment.js would provide a way to deal with cases like this one.

Moment.js is being used by [pikaday.js](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) library which at the same time is being used by [handsontable.js library](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.22.0/demo-date.html).

pikaday.js [doesn't have a callback such as `onBeforeOpen`](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday/issues/488) and handsontable.js doesn't provide it either.

Comment: Not sure if you can customize format regex, anyway note that, as stated in  [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), _Moment's parser is very forgiving_ so `moment("14-Apr random text", "DD-MMM")` will be interpreted as a valid date (`2016-04-14`)

Comment: @VincenzoC not reallym, it shows "Invalid date" https://jsfiddle.net/2w6wa7ga/. "the 'am' matches the 'A' flag.", that's why its valid in the docs.

Comment: in your fiddle you are creating a moment object without the format parameter, this is discouraged for custom formats, as stated [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/). In my previous comment I suggested to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)  constructor that will consider `"14-Apr random text"` a valid date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) *"Moment's parser is very forgiving"* so:

```
moment("14-Apr random text", "DD-MMM");
```

will be interpreted as a valid date (`2016-04-14`).